# Moving uploaded files error

Tags: php

Whats wrong with this code?

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."picture/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
?>

<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='file'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

I'm getting this error: `Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\profile.php on line 3`

Comment: See the Docs! You must add the second parameter: `move_uploaded_file($file_from, $file_to);`

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "picture/".$_FILES['file']['name']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). 
Move-uploaded-file function have to pass 2 parameters:

```
string $filename
string $destination
```

Also, I assume you have mistake in your function. There are 2 params, but you concat them, not separate. Use `,` insteald of `.` before `"/pictures/"`:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "picture/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your full stop before "picture/" should be a comma to separate the parameters, guessing a typo

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "picture/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
?>

<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='file'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

Comment: Yep, just a typo. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, easy mistake.. Where code hinting comes in handy!

Comment: Haha :) You was faster :) +1

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Fuelled by coffee!